# How to create SOAP endpoint in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

Apologies if I've missed an existing answer for this, all I could find was information on making requests *to* a SOAP endpoint...

I need to set up a page/endpoint in PHP that can *accept* SOAP requests (a strict requirement for the service I'm trying to integrate with) and I don't really know where to start.

Could anyone describe the basic outline of what is required?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll consult documentation in future before jumping straight onto StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Put that as an answer and I'll accept it, tar.

Comment: Good to know it helped. The link-only answers are not welcome on SO tho. If you believe the question might help someone in the future, you can answer it yourself exposing your findings with some code snippets.

Comment: Fair point, I shall :-)